# Rails model count by column value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, count

I am trying to count all my items where category = clothing

I have tried both of these ways but it still returns just the number of rows in my column

```
@clothingCount = Item.count(:all, :conditions =>  { :category => 'clothing'})
@clothingCount = Item.count(:conditions => "category = clothing")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both examples in your question have been deprecated. Rails 4 has a different syntax. `:conditions` will not even work in Rails 3.2.

Try this.

```
@clouthing_count = Item.where(category: "clothing").size
```

You can also use [`count`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count), but `size` is smarter. It will check to see if the association is already loaded before running a query. It will also look for a `counter_cache` column.

Answer (score 0):

the count method is deprecated for rails > 2.3.8 versions 
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods/count

Answer (score -1):

// No need to use condition block

```
 @clothingCount = Item.where("category = 'clothing'").size
```

Comment: @cam What rails version you are using

Comment: I am using Rails 4.1.8

Comment: Try this 'code' @clothingCount = Item.where("category = 'clothing'")